# How To Calculate OpenCL Memory Max Limit

Tags: memory, size, opencl, local

Does anyone know how to measure maximum limit or allow range size for constant,local.private,global memory

i use gpu caps viewer tool for cl info and get the result

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lb1y94njg5y37jv/4.jpg

```
Global memory = 2048 MB,
Local  memory =32 KB,
constant memory =64 KB,
```

is that means maximum memory size

the open-cl device info https://www.dropbox.com/s/2fr827ikcrjvoe0/new%20%204.txt

Comment: local: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237181/is-there-a-limit-to-opencl-local-memory , private: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083507/is-there-a-maximum-limit-to-private-memory-in-opencl

Answer (score 1):

Query the device properties with `clGetDeviceInfo()` [OpenCL Doc](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html)

The values you want are:

```
Global - CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE - Total maximum mem size the device can hold
Local - CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE - Local group temporal shared max mem size
Constant - CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_BUFFER_SIZE - Constant arguments max mem size
```

Private is impossible to query, and depends on many things like the code and work size, just use as little as you can.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy using the [Boost.Compute](http://kylelutz.github.io/compute/) C++ wrapper library for OpenCL:

```
// get the default device                                                                                                                                                                                                                
boost::compute::device device = boost::compute::system::default_device();

// print out memory sizes
std::cout << "device: " << device.name() << std::endl;
std::cout << "  global memory size: "
          << device.get_info<cl_ulong>(CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE) / 1024 / 1024
          << " MB"
          << std::endl;
std::cout << "  local memory size: "
          << device.get_info<cl_ulong>(CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE) / 1024
          << " KB"
          << std::endl;
std::cout << "  constant memory size: "
          << device.get_info<cl_ulong>(CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_BUFFER_SIZE) / 1024
          << " KB"
          << std::endl;
```

Which will print something like this:

```
device: Tahiti
  global memory size: 2511 MB
  local memory size: 32 KB
  constant memory size: 64 KB
```

See the [memory_limits.cpp](https://github.com/kylelutz/compute/blob/develop/example/memory_limits.cpp) example for the full source code.